# Confused about computation of integral basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

In Proposition 10.2 in Algebraic Number Theory by Neukirch, the author computes the integral basis for the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, the $n$th cyclotomic field. There is one small computation that I'm confused about:

[image]

Specifically, why does the isomorphism $\mathcal{O}/\lambda\mathcal{O}\cong \mathbb{Z}/\ell\mathbb{Z}$ imply that $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}+\lambda\mathcal{O}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inclusion $i : \mathbf{Z} \to \mathcal{O}$ induces an isomorphism $\bar i \colon \mathbf{Z} / \ell \mathbf{Z} \to \mathcal O / \lambda \mathcal O$. In particular, $\bar i$ is surjective. Thus for any $x \in \mathcal O$ we have that $x + \lambda \mathcal O$ lies in the image of $\bar i$. It can thus be written as $i(a) + \lambda \mathcal O$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now $x \in i(a) + \lambda \mathcal O = a + \lambda \mathcal O$. This proves $\mathcal O \subseteq \mathbb Z + \lambda \mathcal O$. The other inclusion is clear.